# how to throw error message at a time?

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli

i have created a simple php registration form using ajax, i have few issue in my code that when i click register button without filling any of the field 
then it should throw error message saying name is required username is required like this, instead its throwing error message for each field. i.e., 
say if i simply click register button without filing any of the field then i first throw only error message saying enter name. my requirement is to throw error message at a single time for all the fields

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
        <style>
                .error {
                    color:red;
                }

                .button {
                    background-color: #4CAF50;
                    border: none;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 10px 25px;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    margin: 4px 2px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
                .div1 {

                    margin-top: -19px;
                    margin-bottom: -25px;
                    margin-left: -19px; 
                }

                .copy {
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    padding: 6px 20px;
                   border-style: ridge;
                }

                .copy1{
                     border-radius: 4px;
                     padding: 6px 28px;
                     border-style: ridge;
                }

                .copy2{
                     border-radius: 4px;
                     padding: 4px 2px;

                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body  style="background-color:#1affff">  

        <div style="padding-left: 250px; padding-top:50px" class="div1">

            <h2 style="color:#009999">Registration Form :</h2>

            <p><span class="error">All fields are required </span></p>

            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <span style="color:#0099ff">Name: </span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class= "name copy" style="margin-left: 52px"  value ="">
                <span class="namee error"> </span>
                <br><br>

                <span style="color:#0099ff"> E-mail: </span>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class= "email copy" style="margin-left: 48px"  value ="">
                <span class="emaile error"></span>
                <br><br>

                <span style="color:#0099ff"> Username: </span>
                    <input type="text" name="username"  class= "username copy" style="margin-left:26px"  value ="">
                <span class="usernamee error"></span>
                <br><br>

                <span style="color:#0099ff"> Password: </span>
                    <input type="password" name="password"  class= "password copy" style="margin-left:30px">
                <span class="passworde error"> </span>
                <br><br>

                <span style="color:#0099ff">  Age : </span>
                    <input type="number" name="age"  class= "age copy" style="margin-left:62px"  value ="">
                <span class="agee error"> </span>
                <br><br>

                <span style="color:#0099ff">  Date Of Birth : </span>
                    <input type="date" name="date_of_birth"  class= "date_of_birth copy" style="margin-left:14px"  value ="">
                <span class="date_of_birthe error"> </span>
                <br><br>

                <span style="color:#0099ff">  Department : </span>

                    <select name="department"  class= "department copy" style="margin-left:14px"  value ="">
                        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                        <option value="EE">Electrical & Electronics</option>
                        <option value="EC">Electronics & Communication</option>
                        <option value="ME">Mechanical</option>
                        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
                        <option value="CV">Civil</option>
                        <option value="IS">Information Science</option>
                    </select>
                <span class="departmente error"> </span>
                <br><br>

                <input type="button" class="submit" name="submit" value="Register">   

            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".submit").click(function(){

            var name = $(".name").val();
            var email = $(".email").val();
            var username = $(".username").val();
            var password = $(".password").val();
            var age = $(".age").val();
            var date_of_birth = $(".date_of_birth").val();
            var department = $(".department").val();

        if(name==''){$('.namee').text('Enter name'); return  false} 
        if(email==''){$('.emaile').text('Enter email'); return  false}   
        if(username==''){$('.usernamee').text('Enter username'); return  false} 
        if(password==''){$('.passworde').text('Enter password'); return  false} 
        if(age==''){$('.agee').text('Enter age'); return  false}   
        if(date_of_birth==''){$('.date_of_birthe').text('Enter date_of_birth'); return  false}
        if(department==''){$('.departmente').text('Enter department'); return  false}


        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email='+ email + '&username='+ username + '&password='+ password + '&age='+ age + '&date_of_birth='+ date_of_birth + '&department='+ department;


        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gethint.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
        alert(result);
        }
        });

        });
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

gethint.php

```
        <?php



            $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax");

            $username =$_POST["username"];
            $password=$_POST["password"];
            $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $email=$_POST["email"];
            $name=$_POST["name"];
            $age=$_POST["age"];
            $date_of_birth=$_POST["date_of_birth"];
            $department=$_POST["department"];

            $check="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'";
            $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
            $da = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
            if($da[0] > 0) {
                echo "Username Already in Exists<br/>";
            }
            else
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`userid`,`username`, `password`, `email` , `name` , `age` , `date_of_birth` , `department`)
                         VALUES ('','".$username."', '".$hashed_password."', '".$email."' , '".$name."' , '".$age."' , '".$date_of_birth."' , '".$department."')";

                    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                    echo "Registered successfully";
                    } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
                    } 
                    mysqli_close($mysqli);
            }


        ?>
```

Comment: You should not use mysql errors (also because of security issues), but you should check all required  fields in PHP before calling the mysql query.

Comment: You should validate the fields before you run a query. The thing which you are doing is not a correct way of validation.
You can also use jquery validations on client side and then validate them in php using regex before executing queries.

Comment: can u please edit my code and let me know please im new to these concept please sir

Comment: sir can u please edit my code and tel me because im trying what all suggestion im getting but m unable to get result

Comment: _"where as my requirment is"_ Is this a school assignment? Because if so, you need to tell us. There's a huge difference between teaching you something and giving you code that's most likely way too professional for your level. Your teachers _will_ notice the difference. Not to mention that it's pointless to use code that you don't understand

Comment: Yeah you are right. Even serve side validation is required. its true but along with that, the actual concern of him is to show jquery error messages all at once. @icecub

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I know. I was commenting on you because you said it was bad practise without mentioning server side validation. You definitely don't want to give someone a false sense of security

Comment: @icecub yeah right but edited my answer immediately.

Comment: You can just remove the jquery stuff and use HTML5 validation to have the browser do it for you. Then just concentrate on adding it server-side.

Comment: ok i wil try sir

Comment: sir i tried but not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done quite a lot of fixes in your code. They include:

- Set the HTML charset
- Properly closing each HTML element
- Fixed code indentation
- Removed unnecessary spaces
- Turned multiple classes into unique IDs

Changes made to your code:

- Implemented [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object for easier form handling
- Moved each error into its HTML element
- Used CSS to hide each error HTML element

Changes that you still need to do:

- Implement [MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent SQL injection
- Implement Regular Expressions in your PHP code to verify the form data

You'll find comments in the code below explaining what's happening:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <style>
        .error {
            color: red;
            display: none;
        }

        .button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .div1 {
            margin-top: -19px;
            margin-bottom: -25px;
            margin-left: -19px; 
        }

        .copy {
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 6px 20px;
            border-style: ridge;
        }

        .copy1 {
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 6px 28px;
            border-style: ridge;
        }

        .copy2 {
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 4px 2px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#1affff">  

        <div style="padding-left: 250px; padding-top:50px" class="div1">

            <h2 style="color:#009999">Registration Form :</h2>

            <p><span class="error">All fields are required </span></p>

            <form action="" method="post" id="regForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <span style="color:#0099ff">Name: </span>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="copy" style="margin-left: 52px"  value ="" />
                <span class="namee error">Enter name</span>
                <br/><br/>

                <span style="color:#0099ff"> E-mail: </span>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="copy" style="margin-left: 48px"  value ="" />
                <span class="emaile error">Enter email</span>
                <br/><br/>

                <span style="color:#0099ff"> Username: </span>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="copy" style="margin-left:26px"  value ="" />
                <span class="usernamee error">Enter username</span>
                <br/><br/>

                <span style="color:#0099ff"> Password: </span>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="copy" style="margin-left:30px" />
                <span class="passworde error">Enter password</span>
                <br/><br/>

                <span style="color:#0099ff">  Age : </span>
                <input type="number" name="age" id="age" class=" copy" style="margin-left:62px"  value ="" />
                <span class="agee error">Enter age</span>
                <br/><br/>

                <span style="color:#0099ff">  Date Of Birth : </span>
                <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" class="copy" style="margin-left:14px"  value ="" />
                <span class="date_of_birthe error">Enter date_of_birth</span>
                <br/><br/>

                <span style="color:#0099ff">  Department : </span>

                <select name="department" id="department" class="copy" style="margin-left:14px"  value ="">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option value="EE">Electrical & Electronics</option>
                    <option value="EC">Electronics & Communication</option>
                    <option value="ME">Mechanical</option>
                    <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
                    <option value="CV">Civil</option>
                    <option value="IS">Information Science</option>
                </select>
                <span class="departmente error">Enter department</span>
                <br/><br/>

                <input type="button" id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />   

            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var error = false;
            var form = document.getElementById('regForm');
            var formData = new FormData(form);

            // Loop through the form data
            for(var p of formData){
                // Check if the form data is empty
                if(p[1] === ''){
                    // Show the error
                    $('.'+p[0]+'e').show();
                    error = true;
                }
            }

            // Boolean to prevent AJAX from running in case of an error
            if(error){
                return false;
            }

            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "gethint.php",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });

        });
    });
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you alot sir but please can u explain me the script coding?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        //You should concatenate all error in one variable and print it error message containing div. 
        $mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajax");
        $err="";
        $username =$_POST["username"];
        if($username==""){
            $err.="User name should not empty<br/>";
        }
        $password=$_POST["password"];
        if($password==""){
            $err.="Password should not empty<br/>";
        }
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $email=$_POST["email"];
        $name=$_POST["name"];
        $age=$_POST["age"];
        $date_of_birth=$_POST["date_of_birth"];
        $department=$_POST["department"];

        $check="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'";
        $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
        $da = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if($da[0] > 0) {
            $err.="Username Already in Exists<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`userid`,`username`, `password`, `email` , `name` , `age` , `date_of_birth` , `department`)
                     VALUES ('','".$username."', '".$hashed_password."', '".$email."' , '".$name."' , '".$age."' , '".$date_of_birth."' , '".$department."')";

                if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                echo "Registered successfully";
                } else {
                $err.="Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
                } 
                mysqli_close($mysqli);
        }

        if($err!=""){
            echo $err;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: ok sir thanks for suggestion i will try server side validation also